# Inputfields with FieldCompletionFunction keeps list active in previous field

Tags: notebooks, inputfield

I would like to have three inputfields with each their own fieldcompletion list in a row. After choosing an item in the first inputfield (with arrow down followed by an Enter) I want to go to the next inputfield by using Tab.
When I do that the fieldcompletion list in the first field keep active and worse when I scroll down in the second inputfield both fieldcompletion lists are active and it resets the first inputfields item.

[image]

Basically I found it unworkable to use Tab to switch to next fields together with the fieldcompletion function.
An ideas?

```
Grid@{{InputField["", String, 
    FieldCompletionFunction -> ({"fish", "fowl", "fuzzy", "food", 
        "fur"} &)], 
   InputField["", String, 
    FieldCompletionFunction -> ({"1fish", "1fowl", "1fuzzy", "1food", 
        "1fur"} &)]}}
```

Comment: Please report this to WRI Support.

Comment: @Kuba Will do. Seems to be a bug introduced with 11.2. 11.1.1.0 works fine.

Comment: @kuba case is logged. No workaround has been given so it's waiting on a fix